# Check if element in array is Null / Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, null

While retrieving data from a database into an array one of my array elements is (or appears to be) 'Null', as the watch window shows.

However, `pCurveDefinitions(2,0)=Null` return FALSE.

How can I make the check in such a way it returns TRUE?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a different test, like `IsError`, you should use `IsNull(pCurveDefinitions(2,0))`!